# Read Lua table from C

Tags: c, lua, lua-table, lua-api

I'm trying to pass a Lua table to my C program but I don´t know how to do it.

My Lua code:

```
local stages = {}
stages[1] = stage1
stages[2] = stage2
stages[3] = stage3

lstage.buildpollingtable(stages)
```

My C code:

```
static int lstage_build_polling_table (lua_State * L) {    
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

    lua_getfield(L, 1, "stage1");
    lua_getfield(L, 1, "stage2");
    lua_getfield(L, 1, "stage3");

    stage_t s1 = lstage_tostage(L, -3);
    stage_t s2 = lstage_tostage(L, -2);
    stage_t s3 = lstage_tostage(L, -1);

    printf("%d\n",s1->priority);
    printf("%d\n",s2->priority);
    printf("%d\n",s3->priority);

    return 1;
}
```

What do I have to do to run all over the elements? This code generates an error like this:

> bad argument #-3 to 'buildpollingtable' (lstage-Stage * expected, got table)

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table does not have fields named `stage1`, etc., only fields `1`, `2`, `3`. So try

```
lua_rawgeti(L,1,1);
lua_rawgeti(L,1,2);
lua_rawgeti(L,1,3);
```

instead of

```
lua_getfield(L, 1, "stage1");
lua_getfield(L, 1, "stage2");
lua_getfield(L, 1, "stage3");
```

Comment: However, the error message should be `..., got nil`. Perhaps using negative numbers is confusing `lstage_tostage`.

Comment: It returns this error: "warning: passing argument 3 of ‘lua_getfield’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]" =/ ...thanks for you help @lhf

Comment: YEY! It´s working!!! Is there any way to know how many elements the table owns? because in this case I have 3 elements, but I can have 4,5,6...

Comment: Do you know where can I find a sample of this method @lhf?

Comment: @Crasher, I suggest you ask a separate question.